# Find Stored Procedure that Inserts Into a Specific Table teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

How do I find out the stored procedures(using SQl query) that is used to load a specific table in teradata?

Comment: You can't, the only way to get the source code of an SP is a `SHOW PROCEDURE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to yield exact results, but it may help point you in the right direction. You could query dbc.dbqlogtbl for INSERT's into the table, grab the sessionid and look for dbc.dbqlogtbl entry's for `CALL` statementTypes.

Again... grain of salt here, but it might yield something of interest:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbc.dbqlogtbl
WHERE sessionid IN (
        SELECT sessionId
        FROM dbc.dbqlogtbl
        WHERE statementtype = 'INSERT'
            AND username = '<usrname>' /*username that executes the procedure if available*/
            AND querytext LIKE '%yourdatabase.yourtable%'
        )
    AND statementtype = 'Call'
```

Alternatively you could just dump all of the SPL's for your procs and Ctrl+F until you get a hit.

Comment: Nice. As `CallNestingLevel` indicates that a query was submitted by an SP and `requestnum` doesn't change while within an SP you can directly grab the SP name using: `WHERE StatementType = 'Call'
AND ( sessionid, requestnum)
IN (
SELECT sessionid, requestnum FROM dbc.qrylogv WHERE CallNestingLevel > 0 AND ....
);`